# React Leaflet: Event handler function OnLocationfound dont work with map container. How to implement localize me button without it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to implement localize me button to find current user location and move map center to this place. I wanted to use [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/n9lpjj7j9j?file=/src/SimpleExample.js:1002-1017) solution, but MapContainer doesn't have onLocationFound method now.
I also find [this solution](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-events/) but it's hard to move it to button handler instead of clicking on map handling it.

```js
const EventsExample = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null)
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(13)
  const [hasLocation, setHasLocation] = useState(false)
  const [latlng, setLatlng] = useState({ lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 })

  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    mapDiv: {
      height: 500,
    },
  })

  const handleClick = () => {
    const map = mapRef.current

    if (map !== null) {
      map.leafletElement.locate()
    }
  }

  const handleLocationFound = (e: Object) => {
    setHasLocation(true)
    setLatlng(e.latlng)
  }

  const marker = hasLocation ? (
    <Marker position={latlng}>
      <Popup>You are here</Popup>
    </Marker>
  ) : null

  return (
    <Map
      length={4}
      zoom={zoom}
      ref={mapRef}
      center={latlng}
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={classes.mapDiv}
      onLocationfound={handleLocationFound}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {marker}
    </Map>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code was added.